# assets look grainy/pixelated

Tags: android

I'm using pretty high res graphics in my project. I've got different assets in my MDPI and HDPI folders. I've made sure that my manifest supports resizing, that it supports large screens, etc (though this shouldn't matter, at least not for resizing, as long as you declare a minsdk in the manifest.)

The problem is that, all of my assets look grainy and pixelated on devices I test them on. I've tested on a G2x (which is 480 x 800, I believe) and others and it always looks pixelated. When I compare the stock android buttons to my stretchable resources, for example, the difference is startling. My assets look terrible, but the stock android ones are sharp.

Anything I'm missing here to get assets to look good?

Comment: Make sure you are really loading the correct assets. As a diagnostic, temporarily replace the different versions (MDPI, HDPI, etc.) with obviously distinct graphics (e.g., different colors). Are you just setting them as background to buttons?

Comment: yes, they're being set as backgrounds. they are stretching correctly and all, but look like absolute garbage. and i've swapped them out with different stuff, its def loading the right stuff.

Comment: Any chance of posting a screen shot? Also, are these 9-patches?

Comment: They are 9-patches. Uh, posting a screenshot could be a problem. NDAs and all, you know.

Comment: Lemme see if I can just white out the sensitive material and post. In the meantime, just to confirm - what res should I be making these assets?

Comment: It depends on what the graphic content is. If they are a smooth gradient, then you probably want to make them match as close as possible to the size of the views they are supposed to fill. You can also play with the 9-patch boundaries to control what part of the graphic is scaled by the system. If you look at the `<sdkroot>/platforms/<release>/data/res/` folders of your SDK installation, you can see what Google did with their 9-patches at different screen densities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! You must add a minsdkversion to the manifest, e.g. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>` even if you declare that `<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="true"/>` otherwise assets will look terrible.